# Is it possible to change a floor mount receptacle from raised to flush?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, floor

We just built a new home and had a couple of floor mount receptacles put in the living room to accommodate for where furniture is placed away from the walls.  The GC put in raised floor receptacles that are about 1/4" above the wood floors and is telling me there is no way change them to flush mount which I was under the understanding that this is what they would be.  I know that for the current box a hole approximately 4+ inches was cut through both the wood flooring and subfloor, and that the subfloor is used for a flush mount box to set on.  So my question is this, Can a raised receptacle be change to flush mount one?

Comment: There is always "a way" but it may involve more work than your CG is willing to do in order to accommodate your request.

Comment: A picture of your receptacle, with a ruler so we can see how far out of the floor it sticks, might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the type of flush mounted outlet that your GC purchased. One type has a beveled cover plate and is meant to be installed over the flooring to cover the cutout on the flooring. This type is easier to install. The other type has a flat cover plate and rimmed box that is meant to be installed even with the surface of the floor. These are more difficult to install because they require very accurate, smooth cutouts so the rimmed box will fit into it tight and flush. My experience is that those types are usually round and hole saws are used to get the smooth cuts.

If you have the beveled cover plate, it could be changed out to a totally flush type but the problem would be the original cutout would have to match the new one.  If you had the flush mounted one, you might be able to just lower it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Any floor mount receptacle must be listed by UL or CSA as a floor mount receptacle. There is a lot of counterfeit crud available mail order: beware.

Obviously this narrows your choices down to devices approved by UL etc.

Obviously the builder selected a model which sits proud of the floor as you see.  It would be a matter of choosing a different model of flush mount receptacle which actually sits flush.

Product recommendations are not in our wheelhouse here on StackExchange so I can't be more help than that.